# I want to hide my keyboard in all situations

Tags: flutter, flutter-textinputfield, handhelddevice

I am making a barcode scanning application and I am making this application to work on handheld terminals as well. If the user presses the read key on the hand terminal, the return value will be filled into the textfield. I want to not see this and prevent the keyboard from reopening in other setState situations. How can I do that?

For clarity: I focus on the textfield and assign a value with the barcode reading key on the hand terminal, but I don't want the keyboard to appear on the screen. Is there a way I can do this?

```
Container(
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        child: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          controller: editingController,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              value = editingController.text;
            });
            SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod("TextInput.hide");
            print(editingController.text);
            editingController.clear();
            print(value + "aaa");
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a FocusNode() instance to your text field and call focusNode.unfocus() inside onChanged

Comment: Actually, the function I wrote in onChanged already meets this. But when the setState function is called by other methods on the page, it refocuses the keyboard.

Comment: The textfield should always be in focus, but the keyboard should not be visible.

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag did you try solutions mentioned in this thread? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16863

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag could you please apply "keyboardType: TextInputType.none" to your text field? that might be appropriate solution for your case

Comment: 'keyboardType: TextInputType.none' is not working for me

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag do you really need text field here? what if you set the TextField to readonly or simply put the scanned value into a container with text?

Comment: The barcode can only capture the read value in the textfield, I couldn't find a solution other than that

Comment: @VolkanUstekidag did you try adding "readOnly: true" and "showCursor: true" in your textfield?

Comment: "readOnly: true" does not show keyboard but does not read barcode

Comment: what do you use to read a barcode?

Comment: Zebra TC55 handheld terminal - TC55BH-JC11EE. A handheld terminal reads a barcode with a button at the top left.

Comment: What if you remove "autofocus: true," from the textfield? If you set initial focus by using the focus node inside the initstate method

Comment: Keyboard will not open but barcode will not be read

Comment: you're probably using zsdk to work with Zebra, right?

Comment: Yes it's true..

Comment: what about setting "autofocus" by a bool flag? once the barcode is read, you set autofocus to false and your keyboard won't open again (when the setState is called in another place of your page). When you need to read a barcode again - set the flag to true and invoke the sdk method. If autofocus won't work - try the same with readOnly and showCursor

Comment: I'd say that we won't find a pretty solution for your case. The best thing you can do right now is to create the issue in zsdk github so that they will provide an alternative way to get barcode info

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a package I will try it or do as you say.